# Preventing hacking and page redirection

Tags: html, wordpress, url, code-injection

One of our sites was hacked and the visitors were redirected to another site. I have added those links in the robots for blocking. How do I prevent this in future? The site had a WordPress blog which now has a hackware and firewall widget. I am unable to track the source which made this url injection possible.

For security reasons, I am not posting the website link.

Comment: A good starting point can be found here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress Otherwise it all depends on how much time and energy you are willing to invest. You can tinker with wordpress's file system permissions and change them from the default location so rogues won't find them where they expect to be, and you can hardocde your own solutions if need be.

Comment: It was probably an old plugin that got exploited and a webshell or remote code execution script got written to a directory somewhere inside of WordPress.  From there they can run PHP code to create or modify files or just keep sending PHP code in POST requests to run.